# Is it allowed to sort a final list in Dart?

Tags: dart

There is a function with `final` parameter i.e. the given `list` is final. There is no error in IDE when I call `list.sort()`. The `sort` function is a type of `void` i.e. it is not required to create a new reference. But sorting means changing the inner list i.e. the inner reference in memory will change, will not?

```
  Future<void> persist{final List<String>? list}) async {
    if (list != null) {
      list.sort(); // there is no error here in ide
      ...
    }

    ...
  }
```

Comment: `final` means the variable are able to be reassigned to some other object. But it does not prevent the object, being pointed to, to change its inner state.

Comment: @julemand101 probably you mean: final means the variable **aren't** able to be reassigned

Comment: Yeah... Sorry about that confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a dynamic list can change its content even if it's marked as `final`, but it is not the only qualifier that a list can have, it can be simplified to:

- If it has a `var` or `<Type>` then it allows to reassign, modify and resize; with `final` you can no longer reassign it and with `const` you can't change it at all.
- A list can be set to `final` and the list content to `const` effectively making the list `const`.
- Dynamic lists can be created with `growable: false`, this will only restrict the resizing and not the changing.
- Using `var list_a = list_b` will only copy the reference, this measn that `list_a` will have the restrictions of `list_b` even if it has `var`, to make a copy you need to use the `.toList()` memeber.

If an error occurs, it will be at runtime as the ide can not see that `list_b` was originally constant in the same way that casting errors can't be detected.

```
final list_a = const ['C', 'B', 'A'];

final list_b = list_a;
final list_c = list_a.toList(growable: false);

print('A == B: ${list_a == list_b}');
print('A == C: ${list_a == list_c}');

list_b.sort();
list_c.sort();
```